# moved wordpress blog to a new url - sidebar disappeared, but settings are exactly the same

Tags: wordpress

I created a site under www.traumbad-muenchen.de (I blocked google to index that site) and uploaded the content to the new site yesterday (URL: bodenmanufaktur-muenchen.de)

On the old site http://traumbad-muenchen.de/unternehmensnews/ there is a sidebar displayed.

On the new site http://bodenmanufaktur-muenchen.de/unternehmensnews/ there isn`t the sidebar. I have exactly the same settings in the new page. I can`t understand why the sidebar is NOT displayed.

Comment: My guess would be you broke the serialisation of some strings in the database by changing the URL using a simple search/replace. Head to Appearance -> Widgets to add back the sidebar content.

Answer (score 0):

check the widget and theme options in the wordpress control panel. sidebar may be turned off. check if the `sidebar.php` file is included in `index.php` in theme folder and specially is it ( sidebar.php ) copied to new website? and if it doesn't work try reinstalling the theme.

Comment: it's a little small code that includes sidebar.php. it should be written in index.php

Comment: it`s in the index.php but sidebar isn`t visible still

Comment: OK it's time for test and error. create a new directory at your web-hosting named test. then create a new WordPress website in it. upload the theme but not the post contents and see what happens? is sidebar still not there? go simple :)

Comment: hey hadi! It`s not that easy for me to do that test, because that would mean that I do need an URL first. I would like to get this solved without the test you mentioned. I looked at the code with firebug now and the code on the original side looks different than the code on the new side but I don`t understand why and how I can change that. Could it be possible that there is a problem with the database? I controlled all other settings and they are all the same.